# Merge Result Set from Different Query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

is there a way on how to merge result sets from different query? like for example

```
Query A

SELECT DISTINCT HighEnd FROM Chipset

    HighEnd
    ------------
    Class A
    Class B
    Class C
```

and

```
Query B

SELECT DISTINCT LowEnd FROM VideoCard

    LowEnd
    ------------
    Class X
    Class Y
    Class Z
```

and make it something like this

```
    CombinedSets
    ------------
    Class A
    Class B
    Class C
    Class X
    Class Y
    Class Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT HighEnd AS CombinedSets FROM Chipset
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT LowEnd AS CombinedSets FROM VideoCard
```

You can use [`UNION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) to combine the results. This only shows you distinct values for both. If you want duplicates, you need to use [`UNION ALL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Union or Union All

```
SELECT DISTINCT HighEnd as CombinedSets FROM Chipset
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT LowEnd FROM VideoCard
```